# Can you help me find this bulb?

Tags: lighting, bulb

I need to replace the light bulb in my ceiling fan but the part\model number is warn off and I can't find it anywhere! I can read "Philips," "Plus," and "G5" but nothing else. Please see the attached photo. Can you tell me what the part\model of this bulb is and where I can find one (preferable online)?

[image]

Comment: Dupe: http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/67369/8912. (This question's older, but the newer one is more detailed in both question and answers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks a bit like [this](http://www.homedepot.ca/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CatalogSearchResultView?D=136611&Ntt=136611&catalogId=10051&langId=-15&storeId=10051&Dx=mode+matchallpartial&Ntx=mode+matchall&N=0&Ntk=P_PartNumber) - there are a number of options for this type of bulb, the length and wattage can vary.

Probably your best bet would be to take the burnt bulb to a big box home improvement store.  If you have a local lighting specialty shop, they can probably also help.

Comment: Yeah that looks right. Okay, I'll give Home Depot a try. Thanks.

Comment: 1. The link is dead. Say it's a Halogen.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a halogen bulb, take it with you to the home store to compare to the replacements. It's a shame that it doesn't list the wattage, but the g5 may cross reference to something if they don't have the same exact brand.

When you install it, make sure you don't get oil from your fingers on the glass.. They get really hot and oil from your fingers can cause the glass to shatter when it heats up.

Comment: Yes, I had to compare the size of the filament to find the proper wattage. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mention the application. It looks a lot like an automotive/marine type bulb if a 12vdc application, or a 120vac quartz bulb from a spot light.

Comment: It was a replacement bulb for a light on a ceiling fan, thanks.